# Is there a program to make an image sharper?

Tags: image-processing

A friend sent me a picture from 1980.  It's not that clear.  I was wondering if there was a program that can make it sharper?

Comment: If the picture was from 1980 it's likely a resolution issue that cannot be fixed (remember most used floppies in 1980 which were still 100-180KB in size; even the IBM PC that introduced the next year or 1981 had only 160KB per floppy; 320KB & 360KB (DS) not yet common until XT or 1983); ie. a whole floppy is smaller than the average size of a modern image (*and most people wanted to store more than a single image per floppy!*). You gave no specifics; but have you explored the image in `gimp` ?

Comment: This is more a google question ;)  how about https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/11/upscaler-open-source-ai-image-upscale-app-for-linux "that can make it sharper" is also a bit vague. A tool might make it 1, 20, 50% sharper but that might not be enough for you ;)

Comment: Analog picture?

Answer (score 0):

There are many programs that can do that. Many photo editing programs allow to subject graphics to filters, that increase perceived sharpness. In GNU Image Manipulation Program, Gimp, one filter is "Sharpen (Unsharp mask)", which is  found under "Filters - Enhance".

Keep your expectations realistic. These filter can enhance the perceived quality of an image, but they cannot restore information that is not anymore there. You should experiment with the settings to obtain a result that is visually more pleasing but still looks natural.